# scnScene.write not writing the scene to .scn file

Tags: swift, xcode, scenekit

I am working on a project in SceneKit that the user could change the object in the scene and want to be able to save the state of the scene when the user hit the submit button. In the documentation for SceneKit, there is a function call write: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write. However, when I used it following the instruction, it doesn't write to the file. I also used the file scheme like they said in the documentation to create the URL: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url.
Here is my code. Thank you for all your help. This is very new to me so any more advice would be much appreciated.

```
@IBAction func submitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let scnurl = NSURL.fileURL(withPath: "State.scn")

    if(scnScene.write(to: scnurl, options: nil, delegate: nil, progressHandler: nil)){
        print("tis success")
    }
    print("This button work")
}
```

The button does work because it prints out "This button work" but it doesn't print out "tis success" because the function return false.

Answer (score 0):

I'd make use of the last parameter of the [SCNScene.write()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write) method, there's a progress handler there can will potentially give you an error with information if it fails.

I expect it's failing because of the URL you're giving it. Take a look at getting a URL from [FileManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager) and append your filename to that.